# Calculating percentage between 2 Swift Date objects

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, algorithm, cocoa-touch

I have an app with a timer that shows percentage between the creation date of a reminder to the end date.

I have 2 parameters (for example):

`creationDate` : 2018-02-16 17:06:10 UTC
'endDate' : 2018-02-16 15:07:09 UTC

The timer should show how much percent has passed between the 2 `Date`s.

I've tried:

```
let duration = self.creationDate.timeIntervalSince(self.endDate)
let timePassed = self.creationDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
let percent = (timePassed * 100) / duration
```

but the information I got was incorrect.

Does anybody know what's wrong with my algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: What is a percentage of a date??

Comment: @matt of the time passed since the 2 dates

Comment: So that would involve three dates? A start, an end, and some point in time between them?

Comment: @matt Yes, the current date

Comment: Convert all three dates to seconds (time interval) since first date. Done.

Comment: @matt How? (creationDateSeconds - endDateSeconds) * 100 / currentDateSeconds?

Comment: You seem to be on the right path, but *"the information I got was incorrect"* is not constructive. What values do you get for the three variables, and what to you expect?

Comment: @MartinR Sometimes I got more than a 100, sometimes I got minus something...

Comment: I mean a *concrete example*  and *concrete values* where your calculation fails, together with what you would expect as the correct result. In other words, a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you reference date is startDate not endDate:

```
let duration = self.endDate.timeIntervalSince(self.creationDate)
let timePassed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.creationDate)
let percent = (duration - timePassed) / duration * 100
```

Comment: I get `percent=-5.1132038124672805` with `creationDate=2018-02-16 17:36:55 UTC` and `endDate=2018-02-16 15:42:48 UTC`

Comment: if your endDate is prior creationDate, then the percent is negative yes, if you want the percent regardless that condition, use abs()
    let percent = abs(duration - timePassed) / duration * 100

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps (I renamed the creation/end variables from your example to make the answer clearer)

```
let initialDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-1000)
let now = Date()
let finalDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(10000)

let totalDuration = finalDate.timeIntervalSince(initialDate)
let currentRemainingDuration = finalDate.timeIntervalSince(now)

let percent = (currentRemainingDuration/totalDuration) * 100
```

also please note that in your example the dates end date is before the creation date.

Comment: That is the same calculation just with renamed variables.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR for pointing this out. I just copy pasted the lines from the playground and didn't recheck.

Comment: I get 'percent = -4.65048592636217` with `creationDate=2018-02-16 17:40:26 UTC` and `endDate=2018-02-16 15:45:48 UTC`

Comment: it is normal to get that negative value because the creation date is past the end date... it's like a counter 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2 ... 
imagine this... 
you have 100$, and spend 75$. the remaining amount will be 25%.
you have 100$, and spend 100$. the remaining amount will be 0%.
you have 100$, and spend 125$. the remaining amount will be -25%.

same with the dates

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to be more stupid and plodding and systematic when I have to write something like this. Here's a demonstration. We'll calculate how far we are between my previous birthday and my next birthday:

```
// initial conditions
let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dc1 = DateComponents(calendar: greg, year: 2017, month: 8, day: 10)
let dc2 = DateComponents(calendar: greg, year: 2018, month: 8, day: 10)
let dstart = greg.date(from: dc1)!
let dend = greg.date(from: dc2)!
let target = Date() // now

// okay, ready to go! convert all dates to time intervals
let dend_ti = dend.timeIntervalSince(dstart)
let target_ti = target.timeIntervalSince(dstart)
// target is what percentage of dend?
let x = target_ti * 100 / dend_ti
// clamp between 0 and 100
let result = min(max(x, 0), 100)
// print result nicely
print(Int(result), "%", separator:"") // 52%
```

Notice the "clamp" step; this will eliminate your out-of-bounds negative result.